# Swift- using the array in different classes

Tags: arrays, class, swift, methods

I have two classes both for different UIViewController, in one of the classes i have 3 arrays, and i have added those arrays to a NSUserdefaults, now i want to call those/use those arrays in the other class, how do i do that?

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(name, forKey: "ThisContainsName")
    userDefaults.setObject(surname, forKey: "ThisContainsSurname")
    userDefaults.setObject(money, forKey: "ThisContainsBudget")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: What's wrong with `let xyzObjects = userDefaults.arrayForKey("xyz")`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`arrayForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/arrayForKey:) to get the arrays:

```
var yourNames =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("ThisContainsName")   
var yourSurnames =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("ThisContainsSurname") 
var yourMoneys =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("ThisContainsBudget")
```

Comment: If i do this way to get the arrays, suppose in my table view cell i wasn't to se the text equal to the string in the array should i do this way? But i doubt it will work since yourNames is just a variable.
cell.textLabel?.text = yourNames[0]

Comment: It should work exactly that way you mentioned. Just try yourNames[0].

Comment: when i do that i get an error saying [AnyObject]? doesn't have a member names 'subscript'
 if(names?.isEmpty == false ){
            return cell.textLabel?.text = names[0]
        }

Comment: you need to cast your array to stringarray: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("ThisContainsName") as [String]

Comment: i tried as well, still gives me the same errors message.
but this time it says [String]? doesn't have a member names 'subscript'